# Magento2 admin: Send Welcome Email From

Tags: multistore, customer-account, send-mail, multisite

I've got a multisite installation: 2 websites: "Europe" and "Asia". Europe has 2 stores: "France" and "Germany". And "Asia" has only one store: "China".
"France" store as one storeview: "French". "Germany" has one storeview: "German". And "China" has 2 storviews: "Chinese" and "English".

The problem is when a new customer account is created in frontend in "Chinese" storeview, I've got in the backend site in "Account Information" tab "Send Welcome Email from "French" and if I change it to "Chinese" it does not change after saving the modification and the welcome email is sent to the customer in french language. Also "Associted to website" is "China" so it is ok. And in "Customer view" tab I've got "account created in chinese" which is ok. The same issue occures if the customer is created in "German storeview" or in "English". The system always displays in "Account Information" tab: "Send Welcome Email from "French".

Can someone help me please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I change the default website to Europe then the email is sent in french even if the customer registers in Chinese storeview and needs to get the welcome email in chinese

Why is that?